# Ubuntu does not access NVIDIA GPU

Tags: nvidia, gpu, nvidia-geforce, gpu-driver

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.03 on MSI GE75Raider with an Intel UHD Graphics and NVIDIA GeForce RTX2060. Everything currently runs through the Intel graphics. I want to the ability to use additional monitors and run machine learning workloads using the GPU. I have tried to install the drivers 450, 460, 470 (as these appear to be the ones compatible for my GPU) by way of the additional drivers, apt-get install, .run straight from nvidia, the ppa repository (and rebooting after each install). I have followed numerous "guides" and threads with similar issues. I have tried turning off secure boot, doing so in the BIOS.

Thus far none of the normal tips have made any changes.

After I "install" the drivers and run 'nvidia-settings' I get the following error

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

(nvidia-settings:2946): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:34:00.677: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:2946): WARNING **: 13:34:00.679: PRIME: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/prime-supported” (No such file or directory)
```

Additionally running 'nvidia smi' yields

```
nvidia: command not found
```

Any help or guidance, anyone may have, towards a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: All you should have to do is run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` if during system installation you refused 3rd party proprietary software and/or refused install updates over the internet

Comment: As for nvidia smi, the proper command is `nvidia-smi` not `nvidia smi`. Note that the correct one has a hypen, whereas what you wrote has a space

Comment: The nvidia driver may not work with the integrated intel driver loaded.  You may need to go into bios and enable the add on video card, which typically will disable your integrated video.

Comment: Is Secure Boot enabled in your BIOS? Do you dual-boot with Windows? Show me a screenshot of `Software & Updates` **Additional Drivers** tab.

Comment: Good point.  Secure boot can prevent the nvidia driver from loading if the signature isn't properly added.

Comment: @heynnema Secure Boot is currently disabled, and yes I dual-boot with windows. Here is the screenshot
[Add Drivers tab](https://imgur.com/a/M0sswmw)

Comment: At the login screen, select your username, then click the icon in the lower-right of the screen, and select "Ubuntu on xorg/X11". Then go to **Additional Drivers** tab and select the nouveau driver, reboot, and see if the Nvidia card is at least working. Then we'll **purge** all of the Nvidia software, and reinstall from the **Additional Drivers** tab. To check if any Nvidia stuff is still there, before reinstalling it, do `dpkg -l *nvidia*`. All entries should show as `un` for uninstalled.

Comment: Please see my answer. Report back.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any icon on my ubuntu log in. But I was able to follow the windows, bios, and thenpurge all nvidia @heynnema

Comment: So `dpkg -l *nvidia*` shows all as `un`, correct? Reboot, and see if the icon on the login screen is there. You'll see it after selecting your username, but before you enter password. Were you able to select the nouveau driver?

Comment: Once you confirm that all of the Nvidia stuff is gone, and you're running on nouveau, go to **Additional Drivers** tab and reselect the Nvidia 470 driver, reboot, and try `Nvidia` app, and `nvidia-smi`. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema The only clickable icons (at login) are the calendar in the top middle, and the wifi/volume/etc in the top right. There was nothing in the bottom left or anywhere to select "Ubuntu on xorg/X11". All the dpkg packages said 'un' and I believe I am running on nouveau based off of this [nouveau](https://imgur.com/a/77FHg5o)

Comment: Go ahead to **Additional Drivers** tab and now select Nvidia 470, then reboot, then try `Nvidia` app and `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: @heynnema based upon [this](https://imgur.com/a/eTGBh7P) the installation does not appear to work. But `dpkg -l *nvidia*` shows it has installed the packages for the 470 driver

Comment: Hum... we haven't made any progress, have we? You're sure that Secure Boot is disabled? `Nvidia` is not a terminal CLI command. You hit the SUPER key, type `nvidia` and you'll see the app. Select it and see what you get. Otherwise, you'll have to contact Nvidia Support for further diagnosis and help.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for your help here, I'll try to contact nvidia support

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I was able to find a solution with the help of [nvidia support](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-does-not-access-nvidia-gpu-on-ubuntu-20-04/193275)

Answer (score 2):

**Windows**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

**Secure Boot**

Disable Secure Boot in your BIOS.

**Nvidia**

On the chance that you installed the Nvidia driver from the Nvidia site, we'll purge it and reinstall it.

At the login screen, select your username, then click the icon in the lower-right of the screen, and select "Ubuntu on xorg/X11". Enter your password to continue logging in.

Then go to **Additional Drivers** tab and select the nouveau driver, reboot, and see if the Nvidia card is at least working.

Then we'll **purge** all of the Nvidia software, and reinstall from the **Additional Drivers** tab. To check if any Nvidia stuff is still there, before reinstalling it, do `dpkg -l *nvidia*`. All entries should show as `un` for uninstalled.

Then reboot. Start the `Nvidia` application. In the terminal type `nvidia-smi`.